# Python: Edit IP address with range command

Tags: python

In Python

I'd like to print a IP address with range 1 to 254
let say that my original IP is 123.345.4.222
I'd like the output to be:
123.345.4.1
123.345.4.2
.
.
.
123.345.4.254

I've run the command:

```
    IP_to_print = IP[:-3]
    for i in range(1, 255):
      IP_to_print =123.345.4.i
      print(IP_to_print)
```

Question:
How do I add the variable "i" to the value  IP_to_print?
So the print will be: 123.345.4.1 .... 123.345.4.254

Comment: `IP_to_print =f"123.345.4.{i}"`

Answer (score 0):

Check some basics of python.

```
    IP_to_print = IP[:-3]
    for i in range(1, 255):
      IP_to_print =f"123.345.4.{i}"
      print(IP_to_print)
```